# sum two numbers using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sum

Here is my html code:

```
   <form name="sumForm" action="">
<input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" />

<input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" />

<input type="submit" id="sum"  value="sum"/>

</form>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
       $("#sum").click(function() {
                        var num1 = $("#num1").val();
                        var num2 = $("#num2").val();


                        var dataString = "num1="+ num1 + "&num2=" + num2; 

                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "apotelesma.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function() {
                           alert(dataString)

                                return false;
                        }
                });
                return false;
        });
```

and here is apotelesma.php script:

```
<?php

$num1 = isset($_POST['num1']);
$num2 = isset($_POST['num2']);

$apotelesma = 0;

$apotelesma = $num1 + $num2;

echo $apotelesma;

?>
```

I can't figure out how to get the result. I don't know if is correct to include php script to display result.

Comment: I add also a div in html code include apotelesma.php
<div id="result"><?php include('apotelesma.php'); ?></div>

Comment: you can sum two numbers in js also then what is the reason to involve ajax

Comment: Voting to close. You have questions about your PHP syntax, returning values and changing the contents of a div in Javascript. Three questions in one. Break up your problem in small pieces and ask a more specific question if you are stuck.

Comment: There's still an error in the javascript... take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`isset` checks if a value is set and returns a boolean, so `$num1` and `$num2` will be either true or false. So you are not adding up the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `$num1` and `$num2` to boolean..

Try this

```
$num1 = isset($_POST['num1']) ?  $_POST['num1'] : 0;
$num2 = isset($_POST['num2']) ?  $_POST['num2'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php) returns either `true` or `false`, and its is really tough to do any additions with `true` or `false` (sarcasm).

You need to change this to something like:

```
$num1 = isset($_POST['num1']) ?  $_POST['num1'] : 0;
$num2 = isset($_POST['num2']) ?  $_POST['num2'] : 0;

return $num1 + $num2;
```

My question:
Is there any reason you do an addition over ajax? Why not in javascript without the ajax request?

Comment: Last line makes sense there is no use of ajax just to perform addition good

Answer (score 0):

'isset' returns a boolean representing whether the variable is set.

you need:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['num1']) || !isset($_POST['num2']))
    exit;
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];

$apotelesma = 0;

$apotelesma = $num1 + $num2;

echo $apotelesma;

?>
```

then your success callback should include

```
$('#result').html(dataString);
```

When you make an ajax call, your page does not refresh like with a normal form, therefore you would not want to use an include.

Comment: Close. But you may want to check if either post value is set. If one value is posted and one is not, then you will get an error.

Comment: Ok thx but i want to display the values in a div as i said on my comment like:
<div id="result"><?php include('apotelesma.php'); ?></div>
or another way just to display the value.

Comment: oops sorry.  forget to switch my && to || when i did demorgans law

Comment: ok but if i want to pass the variable $apotelesma and display in result div is any way?

Comment: Hmm i did it with .append(data) and it works. Thx a lot guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Others pointed an error in your php file, but there is an error in your javascript [too]:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "apotelesma.php",
data: dataString,
success: function() {
   alert(dataString)

        return false;
}
```

should be:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "apotelesma.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
   alert(data)

        return false;
}
```

The `data` in `success: function(data){}` is what you are echoing in your php file.

Comment: ok i can see the result, alert(data) but if i want to display the result in a div?

Comment: you could use `$("#result_id").val(data);`

Comment: Hmm i did it with .append(data) and it works. Thx a lot guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending the variables. Change AJAX to include the variables `num1` and `num2` in the `data` area:

```
$("#sum").click(function() {
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "apotelesma.php",
        data: {
            num1: num1,
            num2: num2
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And change your PHP to something like this:

```
$num1 = isset($_POST['num1']) ?  $_POST['num1'] : 0;
$num2 = isset($_POST['num2']) ?  $_POST['num2'] : 0;
echo $num1 + $num2;
```